# When does HierarchicalContainer.addItem() method of Vaadin return null?

Tags: scala, vaadin7

Vaadin API Docs says for `addItem()` method,

`Creates a new Item into the Container, and assign it an automatic ID.
The new ID is returned, or null if the operation fails.`

my question is.. **`when operation get failed and why (because isn't it supposed to generate automatic ID ?)?`**

and ya.. it does.. It is happening in my code.

I am simply trying to do as following,

```
 while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      val user_pojo_obj = iterator.next()
      val key = user_pojo_obj.id
      val parent_key = user_pojo_obj.family_id

      var child: Item = container.addItem()
      if(child == null){
        println("Here's that problem..!!")
      }
```

this code executes and after 1 or 2 iteration throws NullPointerException, as I am trying to do,

```
child.getItemProperty("caption").asInstanceOf[Property[Any]].setValue(user_pojo_obj.username)
```

I am trying to filling a `Hierarchical Container` using `Scala`.

Ok. Here's the Stacktrace. `TreeStructContainer.scala` and `ObjectLeveLAccess.java` are my source files.
TreeStructContainer.scala is being used for methods which creates the (Hieararchical) Container and calling those methods from ObjectlevelAccess.java to fill the tree, which is vaadin's java file.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.system.tableManager.TreeStructContainer.getUserTreeContainer(TreeStructContainer.scala:189)
    at com.system.tableManager.TreeStructContainer.generateTree(TreeStructContainer.scala:257)
    at com.analytics.UI.views.ObjectLevelAccess.<init>(ObjectLevelAccess.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator$ClassBasedViewProvider.getView(Navigator.java:340)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:559)
    at com.analytics.UI.AnalyticsUI$7.buttonClick(AnalyticsUI.java:465)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1008)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:377)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:158)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:408)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:273)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:79)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1409)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: @pedrorijo91 Here, it is. [ I didn't covered the 2 items  which are printed because loop works fine for two iteration. I didn't covered it here because I didn't write those `println()` statements in code snippet. ]